# how to add a stopwatch to pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game about falling circles and the player, which is basically a square, has to avoid them. The code is almost done but I have a problem with how to add a stopwatch to the game on the window? I have no idea where to put this type of code can anyone help me? I have all of the code done except for the stopwatch.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import random
import math
import sys
import time

white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
gravity = 10
size =10
height = 500
width =600
varHeigth = height
ballNum = 5
eBall = []

apGame = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("AP Project")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):

  def __init__(self):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(apGame,red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))
    self.dist = 10

  def handle_keys(self):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
      if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit();
        exit()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      self.draw_rect(-1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      self.draw_rect(1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
      pygame.quit();
      exit()
    else:
      self.draw_rect(0, 0)

  def draw_rect(self, x, y):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    '''apGame.fill(black)'''
    self.rect = self.rect.move(x * self.dist, y * self.dist);
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red , self.rect)
    pygame.display.update()


  def draw(self,surface):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))

def show_go_screen():
  pygame.font.init()
  myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
  label = myfont.render("Game Over", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (300,100))


def instuct():
  pygame.font.init()
  myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 15)
  label = myfont.render("Avoid The Circles", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (250,450))


move_x = 300
move_y = 400
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
'''apGame.fill(black)'''
player.draw(apGame)
pygame.display.update()

for q in range(ballNum):
  x = random.randrange(0, width)
  y = random.randrange(0, varHeigth)
  eBall.append([x, y])

while True:

  apGame.fill(black)


  for i in range(len(eBall)):

    ball_rect = pygame.draw.circle(apGame, blue, eBall[i], size)

    if player.rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
      show_go_screen()
      break


    eBall[i][1] += 5

    if eBall[i][1] > height:

        y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
        eBall[i][1] = y

        x = random.randrange(0, width)
        eBall[i][0] = x



  instuct()
  player.handle_keys()
  pygame.display.flip()
  clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: "I have no idea where to put this type of code" well, how did you decide where to put all the other parts of the code?

Comment: `stopwatch` is like your `Player` but it changes value instead of moving. So you can create similar class with `__init__`, `draw`, `update` and use these methods in similar places like with `Player`. In every loop you would have to use `update` which check if it time to change value, and `draw` which display current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not continuously initialize the [`font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) module, and do not generate the [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) objects every time when you display a text. That is wast of resources and performance. Do it once at initialization:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
# [...]

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

myfont15 = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 15)
myfont30 = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
```

Use the font objects when a text has to be displayed:

```py
def show_go_screen():
  label = myfont30.render("Game Over", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (300,100))


def instuct():
  label = myfont15.render("Avoid The Circles", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (250,450))
```

Write a function which can display the time, for instance with the accuracy of tenths of a second:

```py
def display_time(time_s):
  # time string with tents of seconds
  time_str =  str(int(time_s*10) / 10)  
  label = myfont15.render(f"Time : {time_str}", 1, red)
  apGame.blit(label, (20, 20))
```

The exact time time which has passed since the previous frame is returned by [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) in milliseconds. Count the time and use the function to display the time:

```py
time_seconds = 0
while True:

  apGame.fill(black)

  game_over = False
  for i in range(len(eBall)):

    ball_rect = pygame.draw.circle(apGame, blue, eBall[i], size)
    if player.rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
      show_go_screen()
      game_over = True
      break

    eBall[i][1] += 5
    if eBall[i][1] > height:
        y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
        eBall[i][1] = y
        x = random.randrange(0, width)
        eBall[i][0] = x

  instuct()
  display_time(time_seconds)
  player.handle_keys()
  pygame.display.flip()

  time_millis = clock.tick(30)
  if not game_over:
      time_seconds += time_millis / 1000
```

[image]